# Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'

Tags: angular

my page http: // localhost:4200 load correctly, but when i want to go to the link http: // localhost: 4200 /login it return to the link http: // localhost: 4200 and show error

**routing-module.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule , Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { TaskManagerComponent } from './components/task-manager/task-manager.component';


const routes:Routes=[
   { path : 'login',component:LoginComponent },
   { path : 'task' ,component:TaskManagerComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModuleModule { }
```

Comment: how are you trying to navigate to login?

Comment: I just want to show login work!

Comment: i mean is it with routerLink or navigate?

Comment: yes i want to connect routerLink

Comment: hope you are using `routerLink="/login"`

Comment: You need to import `RoutingModuleModule` into your `AppModule`

Comment: You need to share 1) Routing configuration 2) Template where you are using the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component template you should be using something like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Everything was fine, You've created a custom routing module named `RoutingModuleModule`. In that, you are imported your `Login Component`, and you've exported the `Routing Module`. This should work, Before that, I have a question. `

> Have you imported `RoutingModuleModule` in your app.module file `imports` array

ie:

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RoutingModuleModule
        ]
```

That might be the problem, Type importing it and check